# Implementing a synchronized queue in Java using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronization, queue

I've been working on a project where I need a synchronized queue, for the reason that my program is multi-threaded and the thread may access this queue.
I used arraylist to do that, but I seem to have some issues with it and threads got deadlocked. I don't know if the queue is the reason, but I just wanted to check:

```
public class URLQueue {
    private ArrayList<URL> urls;

    public URLQueue() {
        urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
    }

    public synchronized URL remove() throws InterruptedException {
        while (urls.isEmpty())
            wait();
        URL r = urls.remove(0);
        notifyAll();
        return r;
    }

    public synchronized void add(URL newURL) throws InterruptedException {
        urls.add(newURL);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return urls.size();
    }
}
```

EDITS:
Even when using LinkedBlockingQueue I get stuck in the same loop as before. I think this is caused because there is a thread which is waiting for the queue to be filled, but it never does because the other functionalities are done running...any ideas???

Comment: Out of interest, why not use an existing queue class specifically designed for the purpose?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Queue`? Java has plenty implementations of that builtin already.

Comment: I would use an ExecutorService as this wraps a Queue and a thread pool in one.  There are built queues which do what you want, but you don't even need to use them directly.

Comment: If you are getting a deadlock, where is the deadlock occuring as this is the code you should be looking at.  Using a debugger or jstack to see the state of all the threads and find out what it is doing when a deadlock occurs.

Comment: I'll loop up the Queue class and might use it. thank you!

Comment: Please don't use the [homework] tag. It is obsolete and in the process of being removed.

Comment: Your implementation of remove means your producer has to be the same thread as the consumer (if remove is called first, on an empty queue). That's the first thing I notice. But yea, don't implement your own queue unless that's actually a requirement of your homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use `LinkedBlockingQueue` here as it is designed for that purpose. It waits until some element is available while trying to remove an alement.

[LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29)

It provides a `take()` method which

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available

Comment: Though even with this class used in my program, I still get into an infinite loop

Comment: then we need to see your code, there are possibly other problems

Comment: I've edited my post. If you still be needing the code let me know

Comment: "because there is a thread which is waiting for the queue to be filled" you do NOT need this, why are you waiting?

Comment: if a thread tried to take something from the queue, and the queue is empty, what do you suggest I'll do? wait...it's the producer-consumer system

Comment: it is automatically taken care of by `LinkedBlockingQueue`, you just need to use its `take()` and `put()` methods directly without any synchronization/waiting

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `notifyAll()` doesn't throw InterruptedException so you should remove the `throws` from `add()`

The `remove()` method doesn't need to `notifyAll()` as it's action shouldn't wake other threads.

The `getSize()` method should be synchronized.

Otherwise there is no chance for your code to deadlock as you need *two* locks to create a deadlock.